# Problems building through bitrise; more problems building through xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, bitrise

I've somehow found myself trying to build an app through bitrise to deploy to testflight. I'm a total novice at all of this, so apologies for what probably seems stupid.

Bitrise manages to build everything but then finally refuses to deploy, citing the following in the log:

```
[06:06:44]: [Transporter Error Output]: description length:10500450
[06:08:55]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."
[06:08:55]: Transporter transfer failed.
[06:08:55]: 
[06:08:55]: description length:10500450
ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."
```

Fine, I think, I'll clone the repo, open up the project in xcode and thereby update the sdk version. This just seems to mean more problems... When I try to build the project within Xcode, I encounter the following error:

```
Users/[...]/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-x/Pods-x.debug.xxconfig: unable to open file (in target "x" in project "x")(in target 'x')
```

In addition to this, there are a few issues, including:

```
The file "Pods-x.release.xcconfig" couldn't be opened because there is no such file.
```

If I ignore this error, push it and build it anew on bitrise, I get the following:

```
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "DoubleConversion":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)
  In Podfile:
    DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`), DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)`.
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

So, it's looking like there's something badly amiss with the CocoaPods installation. And indeed, when I check into the files, there is no Pods folder at all -- just Podfile and Podfile.lock. (I have no idea how it would have build fine previously without this?)

So, I try to reinstall CocoaPods into the project, by running `pod install` from a terminal in the iOS folder. I get that same error in the terminal: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -- /Users/[...]DoubleConversion.podspec`. `pod update` generates the same error. In addition, I'm told there's a new version of CocoaPods available. I install it using `sudo gem install cocoapods`, which generates a Pods folder with subfolders in ios, but all are empty.

As you can tell, I'm a bit baffled. If an intrinsic part of CocoaPods functionality is missing from the project files, how did it ever build previously? I'm guessing it's due to CocoaPods being installed as part of the bitrise workflow (and it is indeed there) -- but, if so, what about that is now causing it to fail during build? What is it about trying to open up the project to update the SDK used that is introducing this problem?

I'm sure all this seems a bit daft (at least I hope so). Thanks for your patience and any help would be enormously appreciated.